# c# mysql-connector varchar output parameter

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector, out-parameters

I have a mysql (v5.6.25 running on windows 8.1) stored proc which does the following:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `usp_GetData`(IN param1 int, IN param2 datetime, IN param3 datetime, OUT outparam varchar(2054))
BEGIN
    SELECT things FROM stuff WHERE a = param1 AND b = param2 AND c = param3;
    SET outparam = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(otherthings) FROM stuff WHERE a = param1 AND b = param2 AND c = param3);

END;
```

I call it from c# via mysqlconnector using the following:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
command.CommandText = StoredProcName;
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter outparamobj = new MySqlParameter("outparam",MySqlDbType.VarChar);
outparamobj.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

command.Parameters.Add(outparamobj);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", 1);   
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param2", startdate);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param3", enddate);

command.Connection = DBConn; //object set elsewhere but is an open connection.
using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //populate data object  
    }
    //to make out parameter work - ensure the reader is closed.
    if(!reader.IsClosed) reader.Close();
    string outparamvalue = command.Parameters["outparam"].Value.ToString();
}
```

The value of the parameter remains dbnull in the mysqlparameter object, even though it returns a value if i make the call in MySQL Workbench.  If i change the out parameter type to int and return a count of items, this will return successfully so i suspect i am not defining the type of the parameter correctly but have fiddled about with no success.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps you should add the output parameter last rather than first, in the same order it is defined in the procedure.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  I tried that initially but it didn't work - i was playing about with the ordering as i know some return parameters have to be added first.

Comment: @Neil what is the value of `outparamname` also shouldn't the parameter be `outparam` in this line 
`MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter outparamobj = new MySqlParameter(outparamname,MySqlDbType.VarChar);`  shouldn't this be 
`MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter outparamobj = new MySqlParameter(outparam,MySqlDbType.VarChar);` also does `MySql` support `@` symbol when declaring parameters like in `Sql Server.`

Comment: Apologies, i could have made it clearer.  outparamname is a string variable with the value "outparam".  Will edit the question.

Comment: I'm not sure whether Mysql supports the '@' but it doesn't need it for int typed parameters and it doesn't work with or without an '@' for the varchar parameter.